# Best way to remove all characters of a string until new line character is met python?

Tags: python, regex, string, search

Best way to remove all characters of a string until new line character is met python?

```
str = 'fakeline\nfirstline\nsecondline\nthirdline'

into 

str = 'firstline\nsecondline\nthirdline'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the index of the newline and use it to [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) the string:

```
>>> s = 'fakeline\nfirstline\nsecondline\nthirdline'
>>> s[s.index('\n')+1:] # add 1 to get the character after the newline
'firstline\nsecondline\nthirdline'
```

Also, don't name your string `str` as it shadows the built in `str` function.

**Edit:**

Another way (from Valentin Lorentz's comment):

```
s.split('\n', 1)[1]
```

I like this better than my answer.  It's splits the string just once and grabs the latter half of the split.

Comment: I was going to say that `find` is better; if `\n` isn't found, `index` raises an exception, whereas `find` will at least return a sensical value in this case. (Why wouldn't you expect to "remove" the empty string from the original if there is no newline?)

Comment: @chepner:  I initially used `find`, but changed it to `index` because I don't know what the desired behavior is on a single line string.  Is that single line a "fake line" or not?  I think a noisy fail is warranted in this case.

Comment: I think it would depend on what the OP wants to do if there are no newlines. I was assuming you'd want the original string back, but I can see an argument for deleting the entire string instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! I ended up using find because i'm not expecting an response (remote server) without any new lines... if if such condition is met... i'm in trouble :)

Comment: `s.split('\n', 1)[1]` does it in one step

Comment: @chepner: I basically wrote exactly the opposite of your comment to start with, back when it was `find`.  :^)  Noise is good, esp. when the desiderata are underspecified.

Comment: @DSM Your comment is what prompted me to start providing an argument in favor of `find`, and then Steven agreed with you and change it before I could finish the comment :)

Comment: @ValentinLorentz Calling `split` creates a temporary list, simply to obtain a single element, that the posted answer does not require.

Comment: @chepner:  A temporary two item list is unlikely to be much of a performance drag.

Answer (score 1):

str.split("\n") gives a list of all the newline delimited segments. You can simply append the ones you want with + afterwards. For your case, you can use a slice

```
newstr = "".join(str.split("\n")[1::])
```

Comment: This is a bit heavy, as it needs to create two temporary lists.

Comment: I can't really think of a way that's concise, pythonic, and doesn't create two temporary lists. What would you suggest?

Comment: I'd use Steven's answer (although with his original `find` instead of `index`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) ( *regular expression* replacement ) as well.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'fakeline\nfirstline\nsecondline\nthirdline'
>>> re.sub(r'^.*\n', '', s)
'firstline\nsecondline\nthirdline'
```